# Play Enumerator hanging

Tags: node.js, http, scala, proxy, enumerator

I'm using Play 2.1.2 and I'm having some trouble with an `Enumerator` and I'm seeking ideas on how to debug this.

I'm trying to stream some S3 data through my server.  I can get an `InputStream` from the Amazon SDK for my S3 file (`getObject(bucket, key).getObjectContent()`).  I then turn that `InputStream` into an `Enumerator[Array[Byte]]` using `Enumerator.fromStream`.

All this type checks and on my local development machine it all works perfectly.  When I formulate my `Result` in Play, I just return `Ok.stream(enum)`.

The problem comes when I deploy this to a production server.  The very first time I request the file, it works just fine and I get the whole file.  But subsequent times it frequently gets part way through (different amounts each time) and then gets "stuck".  I wrapped the `Enumerator` as follows to be able to log whether the enumeration completed:

```
val wrapped = enum.onDoneEnumerating { println("Contents fully enumerated"); }
Ok.stream(wrapped);
```

As expected, on my development machine (and the first time through on the production machines), I get the message "Contents fully enumerated".  But after that, the production machine will start the download of the file, but it doesn't finish (in both the HTTP sense and in the `Enumerator` sense).

I'm not sure how to debug this.  Obviously, `fromStream` does some magic and I don't know how to figure out what is happening between chunks.  I thought this might be a thread pool issue so I wrapped the whole response in a `future { blocking { ... } }` block, but it didn't appear to make any difference.

I'm trying to avoid the hassle of creating a local temporary file from S3 and then building my `Enumerator` from that.  Using the `fromStream` to create an `Enumerator` seemed like the elegant way to do this...if it worked.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

OK, so I think I figured this out.  It turns out that on the Play side, things appear to be working.  I tried all kinds of variations (different ways of constructing the enumerator, creating temporary files, etc).  It didn't really matter.

What **did** matter was the proxy I was using.  I'm using `node-http-proxy` and if I make a request on the server behind the proxy, I get the correct response (directly from Play).  If I make the request on the server outside the proxy, I get an incorrect (empty) response.  So it looks like the proxy is "dropping" the response.

It appears the issue is that the response is chunked by the `stream` call and this is causing the problem with the proxy.  If I reformulate my response to be:

```
SimpleResult( header = ResponseHeader(200), body = enum)
```

Then play uses the `Enumerator` to construct a complete response (not streamed) and things work again.  Of course, it is stupid to have to form the complete response in this case, but it does work.  Hopefully I can find a better solution than this in the long term, but this seems to work for now.

Comment: Did you find another way for this issue?

Comment: No.  The proxy behavior was beyond my control, so I had to settle for getting rid of chunked responses, unfortunately.